# jQuery UI Droppable - How to actually change the HTML?

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

Using jQuery UI's Droppable I have made a shelf type thing where the items contained on it can be moved. Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/JoeyMorani/7LWj4/

Is it possible to actually change the HTML of the shelf, so when the '.boxArt' divs are moved, they are also moved in the HTML. At the moment it seems to only change the position of the div and not actually move it.

I want to do this so I can detect where the divs are. (What their parent div is)

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some changes to the HTML and CSS from your demo but I have something working. The HTML is simpler and has not affected the result, although if you need the previous layout my answer might not be totally right for you.

The full code is duplicated below as well as in a [**jsFddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TGubd/8/). The code actually becomes a lot simpler after detaching the `.boxArt` and moving it in the DOM, since the animation just needs to change the *top* and *left* back to 0. The only difficult part was calculating the correct position to set the `.boxArt` to before animating. This is due to the draggable being *relatively* positioned to the element it was dragged from. As soon as it is moved in the DOM, this position is now completely incorrect. So the code works out and sets the draggable relative position to the *new* parent first (after moving it in the DOM) and then animates back to `top:0,left:0`.

This is working for me in Chrome but I have not tested in any other browsers. `console.log` left in to show what's going on.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .shelfRow {
        width:1865px;
        height:280px;
      }
      #shelves {
        position:relative;
        width:950px;
        height:566px;
        background:#CCC;
        border:1px solid #333;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        overflow-x:auto;
      }
      .drop {
        width:155px;
        height:200px;
        padding:2px;
        margin-top:30px;
        margin-left:25px;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
      }
      .dropHover {
        padding:0px;
        border:2px solid #0C5F8B;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #0C5F8B;
        box-shadow: 0 0 3px 1px #0C5F8B;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #0C5F8B;
      }
      .boxArt {
        width:155px;
        height:200px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #1F1F1F;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px 1px #1F1F1F;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px #1F1F1F;
        color:#000;
        background:#FFF;
      }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          var shelfOffset = $('#shelves').offset();
          var dropMarginTop = parseInt($('.drop').css('marginTop'));
          var dropMarginLeft = parseInt($('.drop').css('marginLeft'));

          $('.drop').droppable({
              accept: function(el) {
                return $(this).children('.boxArt').length === 0 && el.hasClass('boxArt');
              },
              tolerance: 'intersect',
              hoverClass: 'dropHover',
              drop: function(event, ui) {
                ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));

                var originalOffset = ui.draggable.data('originalOffset');
                console.log('originalOffset', originalOffset.top, originalOffset.left);

                var boxArt = $(this).children('div');
                var boxPosition = boxArt.position();
                console.log('boxArt position', boxPosition.top, boxPosition.left);

                var container = $(this);
                var containerPosition = container.position();
                console.log(container, containerPosition.top, containerPosition.left);

                var newTop = originalOffset.top + boxPosition.top - containerPosition.top - shelfOffset.top - dropMarginTop;
                var newLeft = originalOffset.left + boxPosition.left - containerPosition.left - shelfOffset.left - dropMarginLeft;

                console.log('new offset', newTop, newLeft);
                boxArt.css({top:newTop,left:newLeft}).animate({top:0,left:0});
              }
          });

          $('.boxArt').draggable({
            start: function(event, ui) {
              $(this).data('originalOffset', ui.offset);
            },
            revert: 'invalid'
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="shelves">
      <div class="shelfRow">
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"><div class="boxArt" id="boxArt2">2</div></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div id="drop15"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="shelfRow">
        <div class="drop"><div class="boxArt" id="boxArt1">1</div></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
        <div class="drop"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. :D It also removes the need of that overlap function so that's an added bonus. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yes the droppable _accept_ function (which I actually forgot about and had to look up when developing the answer!) takes care of what your _overlap_ function does. Happy to help :)