# Jquery UI Draggable revert from outside of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Probabely this is a very simple question but i am a beginner in Jquery...

I have following Script:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js">/script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js">

    </script>

    <script>
         $(function() {

            $('li').draggable({
                containment: 'document',
                revert: true
            });


            $("#config").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(ui.draggable).appendTo( "#schub" );
                }
            });

        });


    </script>
```

And this is what my Body contains:

```
    <div style="width:1800px; height:600px; background-color:#efefef;padding:10px;" >
    <div style="float:left; width:1250px; height:580px; border:1px solid grey; padding:10px;" >
        <div id="config" style="background-color:blue; border:1px solid black; width:700px; height:500px;">

            <ul id="schub" style="width:300px;  height:500px;"></ul>

        </div>
    </div>

<div style=" background-color:red;float:left; width:490px; height:580px; border:1px solid grey; margin-left:10px;padding:10px;" id="menu">
    <ul class="category">

        <li  class="dragg"  style="background-color:#e6e6e6; border:1px solid black; width:150px; height:98px;">
        </li>

        <li class="dragg" style="background-color:#e6e6e6; border:1px solid black; width:150px; height:98px;">
        </li>

        <li  class="dragg"  style="background-color:#e6e6e6; border:1px solid black; width:150px; height:98px;">
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Now my issue: I want to be able to drag the grey `<li>` from the red `<div>` into the blue `<div>`. It actually works but the grey `<li>` are always reverting from outside of the window into the blue `<div>` when i drop them. Why is that happening?? Isnt it posible that my `<li>` revert from where i drop them?

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution:

The problem is, that the `<li>` is getting appended to the new `<ul>` in the blue div with the css style he has before ge got appended.

After dropping the `<li>` into the new `<ul id="schub">`, it has still the css from Jquery which is about left:-1000px; (it gets that because we drag the `<li>` from right to left). Then its getting appended to the new ul. 
The browser thinks that the `<li>` is en element of the `<ul id="schub">` with left:-1000px; which is outside of the window. The definition revert:true; is set on the `<li>` so it is reverting from outside of the window into the `<ul id="schub">`.

I actually didn't find a solution, but a workaround:

We can add the definition helper: 'clone' to the `<li>`. Like that we get a clone of the original. Its actually not reverting from the point we drop it but its getting appended to the new `<ul>` without reverting from outside of the window.

Comment: You are correct in the explanation, however there is a solution and that is to _correct_ the position of the dropped element in the `drop()` method. It's a bit of a hack if you can't use `helper: 'clone'` for any reason. Have a look at the demo in my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949049/jquery-ui-droppable-how-to-actually-change-the-html